# How to deploy a CICS application in a web server

Tags: web-services, cics

I have developed my first basic cics application which is an examination system. Now I want this to be available for everyone. I don't have any idea whether this is possible or not. Can anyone guide me or provide any links or books for deploying in a server. Thank you

Comment: Have you mispelled PHP or do you really mean that CICS running on an IBM written in 370 assembler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is in a CICS region, it is available to "everyone" who has access to that region and your transaction.

[CICS is a web application server](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=configuring-cics-web-support-components), among other things.  Those applications can be written in Assembler, C, COBOL, Java, PHP, PL/I, or Rexx.

If your application uses 3270 for its user interface and you want to make it available via the web, you can use a feature of CICS Web Support [specifically for that](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=components-cics-web-support-3270-display-applications).